# using WinApi 32 in Windbg Breakpoints based actions

Tags: winapi, windbg

I was reading about **Windbg Breakpoints-Based Actions**, its like automate the execution of commands within the debugger when a breakpoints is triggered.

for example this :

```
0:005> bp kernel32!WriteFile ".printf \"The number of bytes written is: %p\", poi(esp
+ 0x0C);.echo;g"
```

the idea from this command is to display the bytes that has been written in the file .

ignore the command, just focus on why they used **esp + 0x0c** as an offset for WriteFile API ?
i mean when i checked the prototype of this winapi from Microsoft

```
BOOL WriteFile(
  [in]                HANDLE       hFile,
  [in]                LPCVOID      lpBuffer,
  [in]                DWORD        nNumberOfBytesToWrite,
  [out, optional]     LPDWORD      lpNumberOfBytesWritten,
  [in, out, optional] LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
);
```

and this WINAPI use _stdcall convention because its 32 bit, so the arguments will be from right to left like this :

```
esp+0x00 would be the address of hFile.
esp+0x04 would be the address of lpBuffer.
esp+0x08 would be the address of nNumberOfBytesToWrite.
```

so why in the command above they used the offset 12 and it works not 8 ? is there any thing i missed here.

> the command above is from OSED course

Comment: `esp+0x00` this is return address. so really `esp+0x0c` nNumberOfBytesToWrite

Comment: @RbMm , as i know in win32 the arguments of the functions, first push in the stack and then the return address with the call instruction .

Comment: and so what ? esp+0 - ret address, esp+4 - arg1, esp+8 arg2 and so on for stdcall/cdecl

Comment: @RbMm , in win32, the argument first push in stack then return address then old ebp then variables .
so how would the ret address be esp+0 if the argument are push first , i dont understand ?

Comment: Because after EBP is pushed, it is updated to the current value of ESP.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir because EBP here unrelated at all and not pushed in any case

Comment: @SoronelHaetir so ? i dont understand , could you please explain more or give me a reference to read

Comment: @learn99 when a function is entered, ESP points at the last value that was pushed on the stack. That is the return address pushed by the CALL instruction. The function can optionally update EBP to the current ESP for easier access to pushed parameters and local variables in case ESP is updated elsewhere while inside the function.

Comment: @RemyLebeau , you mean that . because of mov ebp,esp . this make the esp + 0 is ebp ? so to reach variables on the stack for the function, we start from esp + 4 , esp + 8 and so ?

Comment: @learn99 assigning ESP to EBP allows parameters and variables to be accessed via EBP+x consistently in case ESP changes.

Comment: @RemyLebeau , okay i understand that mov ebp,esp will let us using ebp as a base to reach variables . but in above example they use ESP not ebp . how can be esp + 0 be an ret address. this is my question

Comment: @learn99 why is this hard to understand? ESP *points* at the most recent value pushed onto the stack. `stdcall` pushes parameters onto the stack before the `CALL` instruction is executed. `CALL` pushes the return address onto the stack before jumping into the function. Thus, `ESP+0` initially points at the return address on the stack, `ESP+4` points at the 1st parameter, and so on.

Comment: @RemyLebeau , i understand this man, but after call function and prolog then we start calculate offsets right ? why we start calculate offset after the call only ? this is what makes me get wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257249/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-learn99).

Answer (score 1):

0x402020 call Writefile
0x40202x return here

Call Writefile will push the return address 0x40202x before entering the Writefile

So on entry into the function

```
Esp + 0 will have 0x40202x the return address
Esp + 4 will hold hFile
Esp + 8 will hold LpBuffer
Eso + c will hold nNumberOfBytesToWrite
```